# Outlook strange autocorrect

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am writing an email in Outlook and I write something like this:
"also find"
and Outlook will auto correct so it will look like:
"alsof ind"

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I am seeing similar things in Word.

This happens to many words not just those two.

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally added something weird to you spelling dictionary. To remove it Open Word, go to File > Options > Proofing > Auto Correct Options and scroll down until you find that word, select it and click the Delete button.

Comment: This happens for many words all the time not just those 2.

Comment: Have you even checked to see if those misspelled words are in your dictionary? It is possible to add several.

Answer (score 0):

"Alsof"  means "if" in Dutch. Look at your languages settings you might have the wrong dictionary set up as default.

Comment: This happens to many words all the time not just those two.

Comment: But you are positive that your auto-correct language is set to English?